# Need suggestion for C++ design option for passing callback through multiple objects

Tags: c++

So, I have below scenario where X object passes callback function to Z. But I want to prevent Y object from calling that callback function. I have restriction that X, or Z class should not have references of each other, so probably friend construct would not work. Can anyone suggest or give pointers what can be a better design option?

X->Y->Z

For example:
X = Web Interface Object which takes inputs from User.
Y = Dispatcher object which is routing data to other modules.
Z = Database Object which does some processing on the data and call some call backs.

Comment: do you have some uml or more detail about how X, Y and Z are related? Maybe give them actual names so we can understand how they are supposed to interact

Comment: Add a comment to the API of Y: "Y is guaranteed to never call the callback passed through it to Z." Then write tests to verify.

Comment: Too many questions about this as posted.

Comment: You can use abstract classes to provide the interface, with their own friend relationship, and then implement those for X and Z which will then not need to know about eachother. I'll put together an example.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: Thank you for interest. I have updated the post with the object names.

Comment: The details still seem vague. Can you provide some basic _code_ outlines of what you mean -- rather than just `X`, `Y`, `Z` with `X = ...`, `Y = ...` etc? What is `Y` in this circumstance outside of being a `Dispatcher`? Is it concrete, or an interface? Is it user-provided, or just a built-in abstraction as part of a processing pipeline? Way too much that is not stated here. If it's concrete, just document it and test with a mock that a callback never gets called

Answer (score 0):

Based on you description, one possible approach is something like the following:

```
class ICallback;

// A class that can invoke a callback
class ICaller
{
protected:
    virtual ~ICaller() = default;
    static void Invoke(ICallback& callback);
};

// A callback provider
class ICallback
{
    friend class ICaller;
protected:
    virtual ~ICallback() = default;
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
};

// Helper for nicer syntax
void ICaller::Invoke(ICallback& callback)
{
    callback();
}
```

Here, we have some basic interfaces for something that invokes callbacks and something that provides a callback. You can then use these freely as you like. The main point is that only a class which inherits `ICaller` is allowed to invoke `ICallback`.

### Example usage

In a trivial setup, you might have `class X` inherit `ICallback`. For a more general example, you might have `class X` have a bunch of callbacks. Let's go for that, just for fun. Start by generalizing `ICallback` to invoke a lambda of your choosing.

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

typedef std::shared_ptr<ICallback> CallbackPtr;

// Wraps a lambda with ICallback
class AnyCallback : public ICallback
{
public:
    AnyCallback(std::function<void()> fn) : mFunction(fn) { }
    void operator()() override { mFunction(); }
private:
    std::function<void()> mFunction;
};
```

Now, `class X` can provide some callbacks:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:
    CallbackPtr FooCallback(int bar)
    {
        return std::make_shared<AnyCallback>([this, bar]{ Foo(bar); });
    }

    CallbackPtr BarCallback()
    {
        return std::make_shared<AnyCallback>([this]{ Bar(); });
    }

private:
    void Foo(int bar) { std::cout << "Foo(" << bar << ")\n"; }
    void Bar()        { std::cout << "Bar()\n"; }
};
```

Then `class Z`, which doesn't need to know anything about `class X` or *vice versa* can have some sort of callback dispatch:

```
#include <vector>

class Z : public ICaller
{
public:
    void AddCallback(CallbackPtr callback)
    {
        mCallbacks.push_back(std::move(callback));
    }

    void InvokeCallbacks()
    {
        for(const auto& callback : mCallbacks)
        {
            Invoke(*callback);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<CallbackPtr> mCallbacks;
};
```

And you have your intermediary class `Y` which in some way knows about `Z`. In this example, it can just store a reference to a `Z` instance:

```
class Y
{
public:
    Y(Z& z) : mZRef(z) { }

    void Add(CallbackPtr callback)
    {
        mZRef.AddCallback(callback);
    }

private:
    Z& mZRef;
};
```

Using all these for a toy example:

```
int main ()
{
    X x;
    Z z;
    Y y(z);

    y.Add(x.FooCallback(42));
    y.Add(x.BarCallback());
    y.Add(x.FooCallback(123));

    z.InvokeCallbacks();
}
```

### Output

```
Foo(42)
Bar()
Foo(123)
```

So here, even though `Y` is tasked with forwarding callbacks to `Z`, it is not able to invoke these because it does not have the required access.

I don't know if I've really captured your requirements here, but I just want to illustrate one possible way you can fulfill this general requirement. There are other ways you could go about it, but I have no desire to try and capture all possibilities in an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. But isn't we would not be following inheritance correctly, as technically it is not a "is a relationship"?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. "Isn't we would not be following inheritance correctly" does not make sense. The two interface classes here are tightly coupled with a friend relationship, and that's fine. Using abstract interfaces and implementing them _DOES_ describe a relationship to that interface. And that's the whole point.